# Python - socket - sending message to all clients - list index out of range

Tags: python, list, sockets

I have a server.py file which is supposed to handle multiple clients (kinda like a chat) but if I try to send the message received from a client to the rest, I get a `list index out of range` error.

The error is raising at line 15 - in the for loop

Here's my server.py:

```
import socket
import threading

DEFAULT_SIZE = 256
client_list = []


def handle_client(connection, client_id):
    client_name = receive_message(connection, DEFAULT_SIZE)
    while 1:
        message = receive_message(connection, DEFAULT_SIZE)
        print("%s: %s" % (client_name, message))

        for c in client_list:
            connection = c[0]
            connection.sendall(client_name.encode())
            connection.sendall(message.encode())


def receive_message(connection, size):
    message = connection.recv(size)
    return message.decode("UTF-8")

server_address = ("localhost", 4000)
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind(server_address)
print("Server bound. Now waiting for connections...\n")

server.listen(5)

i = 0
while 1:
    client_list.append([])
    client, address = server.accept()
    client_list[i].append(client)
    client_list[i].append(address)

    print("[New connection from %s]:" % client_list[i][1][0])

    thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_list[i][0], i))
    thread.start()

    i += 1

server.close()
```

Comment: Right at the beginning of the `for` loop, say `print(c)`.  What do you see?

Comment: `[<socket.socket fd=304, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 4000), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 50586)>, ('127.0.0.1', 50586)]`

Comment: Does it print that only once?

Comment: No, it prints each for connected client, for example: `[<socket.socket fd=304, (...)]
[<socket.socket fd=320, (...)]`

Comment: The weird thing is that it actually sends the data back only the first time (for all clients connected like it should), even though the error message appears. Then it hangs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) in your code:

```
while 1:
    client_list.append([])
    client, address = server.accept()
    client_list[i].append(client)
    client_list[i].append(address)
```

You append an empty list to the `client_list`; then `accept` inbound connections; and when a new connection is received, you put their details in the list. But when that thread sits in `accept`, another thread that is accessing the `client_list` will now see an item that is just `[]`; and as we well know:

```
>>> [][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When that exception is printed to terminal, that client thread where the error happened was also terminated.

---

The solution would be to append the client structure after `accept` and only after all data is present there:

```
while 1:
    client, address = server.accept()
    client_info = [client, address]
    client_list.append(client_info)
```